# How to choose specific SAP GUI session?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am trying to run an Excel VBA code which uses SAP GUI Scripting.

I have some open sessions in Sap and using two systems "F6P" and "FVP" at the same time.

How do I run on one of the "FVP" sessions?
You can see below there are two session open
One is F6P SAP box and the other is FVP SAP box.
[image]

```vb
Option Explicit
Public SapGui, App, Connection, Session, SapGuiAuto, WScript

Sub Overconfirmation()
    Call SAP
    Call tcode
    End
    Sub SAP()
    If Not IsObject(App) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = App.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Session) Then
        Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
        WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
        WScript.ConnectObject App, "on"
        Set Session = Application.ActiveSession
    End If
End Sub

Sub tcode()
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n/sapapo/bopin"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End Sub
```

Comment: please provide your working code.

Comment: please read this https://blogs.sap.com/2012/11/19/how-to-select-a-specific-session-to-do-sap-gui-scripting-activities-inside-it/

Comment: I edited your question because SAPscript is completely different from SAP GUI Scripting, and not related at all. You use the latter one.

Comment: I have updated my request with more data.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The ID of the SAP system is defined in the property `SystemName` of the object [`GuiSessionInfo`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.01/en-US/15fb37a11e9143eb8eb0e5da85958422.html), which itself is the property `Info` of the object [`GuiSession`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.01/en-US/a4e022f6c155414d9c8ae8eba422cac5.html). You may access all the existing sessions with this code:

```
For connNr = 0 To Application.Children.Length - 1
  Set conn = Application.Children.ElementAt(connNr)
  For sessNr = 0 to conn.Children.Length - 1
    Set sess = conn.Children.ElementAt(sessNr)
    If sess.Busy = False Then
      ' Test Busy because property Info is blocked when the session runs something
      If sess.Info.SystemName = "FVP" Then
        ' Do whatever you want with session sess
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is the solution ! Respect !