# SAP Automation on multiple screens

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I've a question regarding running VBA automation in SAP in two or more screen.
Is it possible if the text hit "1" then the script need to use other SAP screen to run the automation.

```
 If session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-MONAT").Text = "1" Then

'Run FB03 in new sap screen, number 2 or any active 2nd screen
```

I saw this video in YouTube but I couldn't find any respective guide for like this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvLq11HfCTc

here is my current code.

```
If Not IsObject(SAPApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPCon) Then
   Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPApp, "on"
End If


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim rFirst As Range
    Dim rLast  As Range
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long


LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For y = 12 To LastRow

Paymentdate = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & y).Value
'Period = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
Paymentamt = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & y).Value
Assignment = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Value

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("H" & y).Formula = "=Trim(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(G" & y & ",CHAR(44))))"

    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
Range("H" & y).Select

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NF-28"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMF05A:0103/radRF05A-XPOS1[2,0]").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BLDAT").Text = Paymentdate
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BLART").Text = "DZ"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").Text = "ES01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUDAT").Text = Paymentdate
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-MONAT").SetFocus
If session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-MONAT").Text = "1" Then

'Run FB03 in new sap screen, number 2 or any active 2nd screen

Else

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-WAERS").Text = "EUR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05A-KONTO").Text = "115117"
```

Comment: Is this VBA code? And do you use `Option Explicit`? Did you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626050/6600940) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133033/6600940)?

Comment: @Storax Yes this is VBA code and I didn't use Option Explicit.

Comment: Sorry, it is not really VBA code because partly it is VBS code. The part I am talking about you got when you recorded that part of the code ([Wscript](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/4dc0e2db-3234-4383-afba-147154041dfd.asp)). It would be helpful to have all the information. Did you follow the links I also added to my comments?

Comment: @Storax Sorry, yes the VBS connection part was recorded directly through SAP recording. So the difference that i changed were SAPCon and SAPApp.

Comment: So, again, please follow the links, there you will find code resp. hints how to create a new session and how to access an existing session.

Comment: I'm confused by the previous comments about VBA/VBScript, `option explicit`, `wscript`... It looks like valid VBA code, so what's the point?

Comment: @Sandra Rossi: The point is to check the level of expertise. Moreover, it's not valid VBA code. You'll see as soon as you use `Option Explicit`. You will never be able to get `WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"` running.

Comment: @Storax Oh sorry, thanks. In VBA I use `Public WithEvents...` for events, etc.

Comment: So your question is about querying the list of all existing SAP GUI sessions. Does this answer your question? [Find SAP GUI session opened for given SAP system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624238/find-sap-gui-session-opened-for-given-sap-system). Also [here a more simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832774/how-to-choose-specific-sap-gui-session).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After bunch of tries, finally I found the solution to run and choose the second SAP window screen by calling the function from below. Also can switch the automation to run on first SAP screen and next screen by changing few codes below.

```
Dim sapSys2 As String
Set session = getSAPStat2(sapSys2)
```

so then it will be

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-MONAT").Text = "1" Then
    
Dim sapSys2 As String
Set session = getSAPStat2(sapSys2)
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NFB03"
'continue
Else
'continue
```

Full function code :

```
    Function getSAPStat2(ByRef sapBindStatus2 As String) As Object

    On Error GoTo errored
If Not IsObject(SAPApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPConnection) Then
   Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
End If

session_number = 1
Set session = SAPCon.Children(Int(session_number))

If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPApp, "on"
End If

    Set getSAPStat2 = session
    sapBindStatus2 = session.info.systemname
    Exit Function
errored:
    sapBindStatus2 = "SAP session could not be accessed!"
End Function
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your answer which tells the user to get the answer in the code, that's worth explaining the solution in full words. By reading your code, I now realize what your question was, one better answer already exists.